# How to get pandas dataframe index from "int64" to "Datetime" typedatetime type by using only year as reference to be compatible with statsmodels)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which looks as follows:

```
    Values
Year    
2010    0.72
2011    0.61
2012    0.64
2013    0.67
2014    0.74
2015    0.89
2016    1.01
2017    0.92
2018    0.84
2019    0.97
2020    1.01
2021    0.84
```

`df.to_dict()` returns the following:

```
{'Values': {2010: 0.72,
  2011: 0.61,
  2012: 0.64,
  2013: 0.67,
  2014: 0.74,
  2015: 0.89,
  2016: 1.01,
  2017: 0.92,
  2018: 0.84,
  2019: 0.97,
  2020: 1.01,
  2021: 0.84}}
```

I want to convert the index into datetime type.

I used

```
 df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

However, it returned me the following:

```
    Values
Year    
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002010   0.72
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002011   0.61
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002012   0.64
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002013   0.67
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002014   0.74
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002015   0.89
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002016   1.01
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002017   0.92
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002018   0.84
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002019   0.97
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002020   1.01
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002021   0.84
```

The year is 1970 in the entire index, which is weird.
Also, the actual years that need to be in the index are towards the end of the decimal points.

I also tried

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format = "%Y").year
```

However, the index does not change to "datetime" type and it is still of "int64" type.

I need the index to be of "datetime" type to run `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose(df)`.

Is it possible to change the index to datetime type using only year as reference? If not, what would be the optimal alternative solution?

Comment: Use `pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y')`

Comment: conceptually you're better off with `pd.PeriodIndex(..., freq="Y")` (not a timestamp you have, but rather a period) and statsmodels should be happy with it. also Jan 1 1970 is the UNIX epoch time beginning, and direct `pd.to_datetime` interprets your integers as nanoseconds so it's "1 january 1970, 2012 nanoseconds" and so on

Comment: If `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose(df)` allows for period indices then that is the best solution.

Comment: Don't apply `...(...).year` after converting to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

`year` returns an `int64` representing the year. If you want to keep it as a datetime, just cut use `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format = "%Y")`.

Comment: But then I just want year in the index. This would still return month and day in the index which I don't want.

Comment: @hbstha123 IMO you're confusing the idea of dates as a type and there representation in some format. Also, if a month and day doesn't matter at all then why even use the datetime?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Vitalizzare